# Install npm package globally on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, phantomjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to install an npm package globally on elastic beanstalk. This is what my config file looks like which I wrote based on this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).

```
container_commands:
  install_phantom:
    command: "npm install phantomjs -g"
```

And when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk I get this error

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred
>   during build: Command install_phantom failed .

Comment: One thing I've found is that `npm` is not included in the path, but instead located at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/npm`

Comment: Loourr - Did you have any luck with this? I've tried the above command, including specifying the exact path of npm, but the command always fails.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335301/no-path-when-executing-commands-in-elastic-beanstalks-container-commands), have you tried:

```
container_commands:
  install_phantom:
    command: "export PATH=$PATH; npm install phantomjs -g"
```

Comment: This solution does not work (atleast right now) - trying this gives `npm: command not found`. For path, this works: https://gist.github.com/dduvnjak/3b21e247c9fcd409a12d

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable for the node installation is NODE_HOME, so you should do this, to run npm or node in a container command in your config files:

```
container_commands:
  install_phantom:
    command: bash -c "PATH=$PATH:$NODE_HOME/bin npm install phantomjs -g"
```

Comment: This solution does not work (atleast right now) - trying this gives `npm: command not found`. For path, this works: https://gist.github.com/dduvnjak/3b21e247c9fcd409a12d